# ¿Por que angular-tour no funciona en la vista?

Tags: angularjs

Estoy utilizando la librería [angular-tour](http://daftmonk.github.io/angular-tour/) que me servira guiar al usuario en caso tenga dudas de ciertas funcionalidades de la pantalla.

Pero no logro hacer que me funcione.

En el archivo `index.html`, tengo importado:

```
<link rel="bower_components/angular-tour/dist/angular-tour.css"/> //en la parte del encabezado del index.
<script src="../bower_components/angular-tour/dist/angular-tour-tpls.min.js"></script> //hasta la parte final, luego de haberse cargado jquery y angularjs
```

En mi archivo `app.js` importo el respectivo módulo.

```
angular.module("app", [
        "authService",
        /* Angular modules */
        "ngRoute",
        "ngAnimate",
        "ngSanitize",
        "ngAria",
        "ngMaterial",

        /* 3rd party modules */
        "oc.lazyLoad",
        "ui.bootstrap",
        "angular-loading-bar",
        "FBAngular",

        /* custom modules */
        "app.ctrls",
        "app.directives",
        "app.ui.ctrls",
        "app.ui.directives",
        "app.form.ctrls",
        "app.table.ctrls",
        "app.email.ctrls",
        "app.todo",
        "toastr",
        "angular-tour", //aca el modulo de angular tour
        "satellizer"
    ])
```

En el controlador de esta forma:

```
angular.module("Usuarios", [])
    .controller("UsuariosCtrl", ["$scope", "$modal", "$http", "$filter", "$modalStack", "$route", "$timeout", "toastr", function($scope, $modal, $http, $filter, $modalStack, $route, $timeout, toastr) {
//-------- Tour AngularJS --------------
        $scope.currentStep= 0; 
        //--------------------------------------        
    }])
}())
```

Y en mi vista lo tengo de esta forma:

```
<div class="page page-forms-imagecrop">
    <ol class="breadcrumb breadcrumb-small">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#/usuarios">Usuarios</a></li>
        <div class="toast toast-{{positionModel}}">
            <alert ng-repeat="toast in toasts" type="{{toast.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)" class="toast-{{toast.anim}}">
                <div ng-bind-html="toast.msg"></div>
            </alert>
        </div>          
    </ol>
    <div class="page-wrap">
        <div class="row">
           <tour step="currentStep">
              <span tourtip="tip 1"> Highlighted </span>
              <span tourtip="tip 2"> Elements </span>
              <input tourtip="You can use it as an attribute on your element" />
              <span tourtip="Full options"
              tourtip-step="2"
              tourtip-next-label="Next"
              tourtip-placement="right"
              tourtip-container-element="body"
              tourtip-margin="0"
              tourtip-offset-vertical="0"
              tourtip-offset-horizontal="0"
              on-show="someFunc"
              on-proceed="someFunc">Full options</span>
          </tour>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

En consola no me muestra ningún error y en la vista únicamente se ve el HTML pero sin la funcionalidad del tour. El controlador si me funciona ya que utilizo otras funcionalidades como el *toast* y demás funciones que no agregué completo en el controlador.

De antemano muy agradecido.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de jQuery utilizas en tu proyecto?

Comment: Veo que llamas los estilos del componente con  `<link rel="bower_components/` y el js lo llamas con `<script src="../bower_components/`, es decir, agregas `...`. ¿Verificaste que puedas acceder a los estilos?

Comment: Muchas gracias @AngelOropeza me ha funcionado tu respuesta, por favor podrias ayudarme con esta otra, es referente a la misma libreria. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/208817/como-ejecutar-angular-tour-%C3%BAnicamente-cuando-presionen-un-bot%C3%B3n gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer al trabajar con **jQuery 3** no esta funcionando correctamente pero el problema ya fue identificado en el siguiente *issue*: [Not working with jQuery 3](https://github.com/DaftMonk/angular-tour/issues/83#issuecomment-275708877) del [repositorio](https://github.com/DaftMonk/angular-tour/) del proyecto.

Cito el comentario del usuario [**hprofit**](https://github.com/hprofit) (*traducido al español*):

> @tvsbrent @booleanbetrayal @DaftMonk
>
> El problema proviene de [jQuery 3.1.1's .fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) que no esta adjuntando `display: block;` a el elemento contenedor `div.tool-tip`. Configurando `tourConfig.animation = false;` evitarás este problema, pero pierdes el efecto de desvanecimiento.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Necesitas inyectar el servicio `tourConfig` en tu controlador y añadir la siguiente línea `tourConfig.animation = false;`.

Para tu caso quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
angular.module("Usuarios", [])
    .controller("UsuariosCtrl", ["$scope", "$modal", "$http", "$filter", "$modalStack", "$route", "$timeout", "toastr", "tourConfig", function($scope, $modal, $http, $filter, $modalStack, $route, $timeout, toastr, tourConfig) {
//-------- Tour AngularJS --------------
        tourConfig.animation = false;
        $scope.currentStep= 0; 
        //--------------------------------------        
    }])
}())
```

En [Plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/fpu62pE1gCfG1APm) puedes encontrar un proyecto que hice para probarlo en caso de que tengas alguna duda.

Por otra parte este componente no causa problema si se esta trabajando con **jQuery Core 2.2.4** y **jQuery Core 1.12.4**.

Comment: estoy utilizando la versino 2.1.3