# ¿Como ejecutar angular-tour únicamente cuando presionen un botón?

Tags: angularjs

Buen dia. Estoy utilizando la librería [angularjs-tour](http://daftmonk.github.io/angular-tour/) y lo tengo inicializado el de la siguiente forma:

```
<tour step="currentStep">
     <virtual-step
        tourtip="Boton para realizar el registro de los usuarios a la plataforma"
        tourtip-step="0"
        tourtip-next-label="Siguiente"
        tourtip-placement="bottom"
        tourtip-element=".btn-line-success">
     </virtual-step>
     <virtual-step
        tourtip="Campo para realizar una busqueda de los usuarios existentes"
        tourtip-step="1"
        tourtip-next-label="Siguiente"
        tourtip-placement="bottom"
        tourtip-element=".form-horizontal">
     </virtual-step>
    <button ng-click="openTour()">Open Tour</button>
    <button ng-click="closeTour()">Close Tour</button>
</tour>
```

El cual me trabaja muy bien, si presiono el boton con la función `openTour()` correctamente inicia el tour o si le presiono el botón `closeTour()` cierra el recorrido.
En el controlador unicamente tengo la siguiente línea:

```
//-------- Tour AngularJS --------------
        $scope.currentStep= 0; 
//--------------------------------------
```

Pero tengo el detalle de que cada vez que recargo la vista por ejemplo, se inicializa el tour, pero necesito que el tour solamente se ejecute hasta que el usuario presione `openTour()` ya que solo servira para ayuda al usuario en caso necesite saber para qué sirve tal opción de la vista.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la documentación [*How to use*](https://github.com/DaftMonk/angular-tour#how-to-use) hay una nota que dice lo siguiente:

> Nota: si no inicializa `currentStep` en su controlador, se establecerá de manera predeterminada a `-1`, lo que significa que el recorrido no aparecerá al cargar la página. Esto causa incompatibilidad con anteriores verisones, ya que anteriormente `currentStep` era por defecto `0`, lo que provocaba que el recorrido se iniciará automáticamente.

En tu caso bastará con cambiar la siguiente línea a `-1`:

```
$scope.currentStep = -1;
```

También intente no inicializar la variable en el controlador pero al parecer el cambio que indican en la nota no está funcionando en esta versión.

Creé un [*Plunker*](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/rerIEMgFf5SpOujh?preview) con estos cambios.

Comment: Es extraño que utilizando esa misma configuracion de -1 no me funciona, hasta que utilice las etiquetas <span>.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Por si aún te interesa actualice el proyecto en *Plunker* para que funcione con `<virtual-step tourtip="" tourtip-element=""></virtual-step>`